# Monthly average rate of discount, 3 month Treasury bills, Sterling Vs 1 Month

Tags: econometrics, finance, financial-economics, financial-markets, regression

I have been advised by one of my professors to use UK treasury bills for a risk free rate when calculating expected returns for stocks.

I wanted to know whether I should be using 1 month T-Bills or 3 month T-bills.

1. Which is better to use and why?
2. My lecturer mentioned that the risk free rates I download will be annualized percent figures (although % notation may or may not be there), so I would need to convert them to daily rates before I can you use them in regressions. Does anyone know where I can obtain this data? I found the 1 month and 3 month T-bills data on the Bank of England website. I need to know how to get the daily data for these T-bills.

Comment: Is it not the case that the shorter the maturity the lower the risk? In any case, it is unlikely the UK government will ever default on its 1M or 3M T-bills (the last time [it was rescued by the IMF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_British_national_debt#1970s)) so they probably have a very similar risk. I would rather use whichever has more data.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer to your first question**
Take a look at what Aswath Damadoran uses for his empirical work. He's been teaching applied corporate finance for a little while at NYU. [These are his slides.](http://people.stern.nyu.edu/adamodar/pdfiles/eqnotes/dcfrates.pdf)

**Answer to your second question**
If you have access to any of the following, you should have no problem getting access to any economic and financial time series.

- Datastream
- Bloomberg

Also try [FRED database](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/)

Answer (score 0):

There are different oppinions on which rates to use for calculating expected return (I assume you mean throu CAPM?).

Most, however, do agree that it should be long-term risk-free, so 1 and 3-month T-Bills are going to be way to short a timespan. Usually you would go with 10 to 30 year government bonds.

My professor in B-School recommended 10-year government bonds for a similar case.

Comment: I agree with you, 10 to 30 year would be much more ideal.However I am dealing with a 2 year window (2015-2017). I am working on the FTSE all shares index returns before and after Brexit. With estimation window from the start of 2015 up till 1 month before the referendum and then the second window is post referendum up till now. I am working with daily data.

Comment: If you are dealing with historical figures - then I guess you should use historical rates for 10 year bonds back in 2015 to 2017. Consider if your 2-year timeperiod was in 1994-1995, then using todays rates would be wrong - same thing here, expect the historical figures are not that old.